# Can I perform global changes to all post page settings with mySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I’m doing a complete site rebuild. I’ve imported all the blog posts from old site, but the blog posts imported with the "default" setting of Post Options > Sidebar Position > None (when on the WP post edit page).

Is there anyway to do a global change to all post pages? I want all pages to have a right sidebar.

There are hundreds so I *really* don’t want to do it individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a default/core WordPress option.
It probably is a theme functionality that is stored in the wp_postmeta table, so you might want to go this route:

- Find out where the "show sidebar for post" is stored in the database (wp_postmeta table probably)
- Find out what the value for "showing the sidebar" is
- Do an update, something like this: `update wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'show' where meta_key = 'blog_post_sidebar';`

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a look.